# Compare multiple pairs of x/y columns after left join and if different use y in R

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, tidyr

I have a data.frame `df1`. Some selected rows have been manually reviewed and updated, creating a second data.frame `df1updated` which has all the same columns, where some of the data has been changed, plus additional columns.

I want to join the updated version to the original and, where the data has been change, replace the original, where there has been no change, retain the original, where the data has not been reviewed (i.e. is not in `df1updated`) retain the original

I have done this in this small example as follows:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 =  data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  date = dmy(c("15/01/2020", "03/12/2020", "20/08/2019" , "01/01/2021", "01/02/2021")),
                  type = c("type_A","type_A", "type_B", "type_C", "type_B"))


df1_update = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 date = dmy(c("25/01/2020", "03/12/2020", "20/08/2019")),
                 type = c("type_A","type_B", "type_B"),
                 new_info = c("note", "nil","note"))

df3 = left_join(df1, df1_update, by = "id")%>%
  mutate(date = case_when(is.na(date.y) ~ date.x, 
                          date.x == date.y ~ date.x,
                          date.x != date.y ~ date.y),
         type = case_when(is.na(type.y) ~type.x,
                          type.x == type.y ~ type.x,
                          type.x != type.y ~ type.y))%>%
  select(-contains(c(".x", ".y"))) 

df3

> df3
  id new_info       date   type
1  1     note 2020-01-25 type_A
2  2      nil 2020-12-03 type_B
3  3     note 2019-08-20 type_B
4  4     <NA> 2021-01-01 type_C
5  5     <NA> 2021-02-01 type_B
```

In my real data set I have around 16 columns that have been reviewed and updated. Is it possible to compare all pairs of columns ending in .x and .y without having to name each pair as I have above? I'm guessing it may be possible by writing a function.

Here are examples of real column names, after left_join:

"Access_ID"                                     "First_use_Date_After_Creation.x"          "Last_use_Date"
[13]  "StatusOnAccessDay.x"
[43] "Access_Type.y"                                 "Access_Site.y"                                 "StatusOnAccessDay.y"
[46] "Date_Construction.y"                           "Date_Of_First_Use.y"                           "First_use_Date_After_Creation.y"
[49]  "Date_Of_failure.y"                             "Date_Of_removal.y"
[52]    "Problem_item" "Problem_item.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier with `coalesce` (if there are not much conditions or else  can use `case_when`).  In addition, assuming that there are always `.y` columns for the corresponding `.x` column, loop `across` the `.x` columns, replace the substring `.x` of the column name (`cur_column()`) with `.y`, `get` the value, apply `case_when`, update the column name within `.name` and remove the `unused` columns using `.keep`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
left_join(df1, df1_update, by = "id") %>% 
   mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), 
   ~ {
      xdat <- as.character(.x)
      ydat <- as.character(get(str_replace(cur_column(), '\\.x', '.y')))
      case_when(is.na(ydat) ~ xdat, 
              xdat == ydat ~ xdat,
               xdat != ydat ~ ydat)
     }, 
      .names = "{str_remove(.col, '.x')}"), .keep = 'unused') %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 id new_info       date   type
1  1     note 2020-01-25 type_A
2  2      nil 2020-12-03 type_B
3  3     note 2019-08-20 type_B
4  4     <NA> 2021-01-01 type_C
5  5     <NA> 2021-02-01 type_B
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with a function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

coalesce_from_base <- function(df, base) {
  
  .x <- paste0(base, ".x")
  .y <- paste0(base, ".y")
  
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!ensym(base) := case_when(is.na(.data[[.y]]) ~ .data[[.x]], 
                                      .data[[.x]] == .data[[.y]] ~ .data[[.x]],
                                      .data[[.x]] != .data[[.y]] ~ .data[[.y]])) 
  
}

# join together
df3 <- left_join(df1, df1_update, by = "id")

# create a vector a fields to iterate over
col_base <- c("date", "type")
# col_base <- stringr::str_subset(names(df3), ".x$") # create this by code

# use reduce to cumulative iterate over each base value
reduce(col_base, coalesce_from_base, .init = df3) %>%
  select(-ends_with(c(".x", ".y")))
```